# Typo3: page link in menu using value from custom record

Tags: menu, hyperlink, field, typo3, record

I have :

- a 3 level menu
- custom records from a table called
  "tx_products_domain_model_product"
- products have a field called "url_alias"

On any page on that menu, I can have a product record.
For pages that have a product record I want the link to look like:

```
http://www.sitedomain.com/<url_alias>
```

Can this be done with typoscript?

**EDIT**

It looks like it's too complex to do all this with typoscript, so I'm using a userFunc. I'm checking if there is a product record with a shop ID and want to return that shop id. If not, return the current menu page UID. The problem is, how can I pass the menu page UID as parameter to the userFunc?

```
class user_productsOnCurrentPage
{
    function main( $content, $conf )
    {
        if ( TYPO3_MODE !== 'FE' )
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $product = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetSingleRow(
                'shop_id', 'tx_products_domain_model_product', 'pid=' . $conf['currentPageId'] . ' AND deleted=0 AND hidden=0' );

        if ( is_array( $product ) && ! empty( $product ['shop_id'] ) )
        {
            return $product ['shop_id'];
        }

        return $conf['currentPageId'];
    }
}
```

The menu:

```
lib.mainMenu = HMENU
lib.mainMenu {
    ...
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        ...
        NO = 1
        NO {
            ...
            # show direct url for external links
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            stdWrap.cObject = CASE
            stdWrap.cObject {
                key.field = doktype
                default = TEXT
                default {
                    field = nav_title // title

                    typolink.parameter.cObject = USER
                    typolink.parameter.cObject {
                        userFunc = user_productsOnCurrentPage->main
                        currentPageId = ?????
                    }

                    typolink.wrap = |<span><strong></strong></span>
                    typolink.ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                    stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
                }
                ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could access the page ID directly in the user function:

TypoScript:

```
typolink.userFunc = user_mcfazabosOnCurrentPage->main
```

PHP:

```
$pageId = $this->cObj->getFieldVal( 'uid' );
```